# Why the electric field inside a solid sphere is non-zero according to gauss while we know that the electric field inside a conductor is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

We know that the electric field inside a conductor is zero, but in my book, according to Gauss' law,
the electric field inside a solid sphere (it's not mentioned if it's a conductor or non-conductor) is
$$E = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{r}{R^3}$$

Comment: This a  sphere with a uniformly distributed electric charge, so obviously not a conductor.

Comment: Thanks :). Now I can go back to sleep :)